# SQL Left Join and include NULL record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Item AS i
LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemSpecific AS is ON i.ID = is.ID


dbo.Item
ID
Name
Description

dbo.ItemSpecfic
ID
ItemID
Name
Description
```

As you will notice the dbo.ItemSpecific table contains the same columns as the dbo.Item table. If there is customization at an account level for an item, the specifics are in the dbo.ItemSpecific table, otherwise if the account just uses the standard Item, there will be no dbo.ItemSpecific record at all.

What I am trying to do is get a list of all of the specific records for each of the accounts, and also the standard item records that the accounts will use if they do not have customization. Is there a way to do this in a single query or is a union my only option? With the left join right now the regular dbo.Item record is not being returned if there are any customizations, as then the join is fulfilled.

An example of the data I want is as follows:

```
ItemID       ItemSpecificID       Name         Description
1                   1             'Test'         'Test'
2                  NULL           'Test2'        'Test2'
2                   2             'Test3'        'Test3'
2                   3             'Test4'         'Test4'
```

Comment: COALESCE is your friend

Comment: Can you show an example of the results that you want?

Comment: I am using COALESCE to get the item specific columns where needed but I also need the individual record as a separate record for the results.

Comment: Just a quick comment: don't use `is` as an alias; it's bad practice (because `IS` means something to SQL, e.g., in `IS NULL`).

Comment: Added Example, you will notice that Item 2 has 2 account specific items but it also still shows the admin record

Answer (score 0):

[FULL OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) is your friend.

[image]

```
FROM
    dbo.Item I
    FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemSpecific IS ON I.Id = IS.ItemID
```

Comment: This is also not working. I believe it is the same thing in the fact that it is already satisfying the JOIN because there are records in the dbo.ItemSpecific table for that Item so it only returns 2 records.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT i.ID,
       isp.ItemSpecificID,
       Isnull(isp.Name, i.Name) Name,
       Isnull(isp.[Description], i.[Description]) [Description]
FROM dbo.Item AS i
LEFT outer JOIN dbo.ItemSpecific AS isp ON i.ID = isp.ItemID
```

[image: Real Result]

Comment: The problem with this is that the LEFT JOIN is removing the Item record all together because the join is satisfied so in the example above, ItemID 2 would only show 2 records with this instead of 3.

Comment: @mameesh I think it is correct, did you check that?, pay attention that it is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` not `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: That returns the exact same results, LEFT JOIN AND LEFT OUTER JOIN are exactly the same thing in SQL.

Comment: Your problem is probably related to having similarly named columns in both tables and doing a `select *`

Comment: @mameesh  If you have data just run the query and tell what is the result.

Comment: SELECT 1 AS ItemID, 'TestingAdmin' AS Name, 'TestingName' AS Description
INTO #Item
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ItemID, 'Test2', 'Test2'

Comment: SELECT 1 AS ItemSpecificID, 1 AS ItemID, 'Test' AS Name, 'Test' AS Description
INTO #ItemSpecific
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ItemSpecificID, 2 AS ItemID, 'Test3' AS Name, 'Test3' AS Description
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ItemSpecificID, 2 AS ItemID, 'Test4' AS Name, 'Test4' AS Description

Comment: SELECT i.ItemID,
       isp.ItemSpecificID,
       Isnull(isp.Name, i.Name) Name,
       Isnull(isp.[Description], i.[Description]) [Description]
FROM #Item AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ItemSpecific AS isp ON i.ItemID = isp.ItemID

Comment: No that's not what the original question is. The original question is to show 3 records for ItemID = 2.

Comment: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/difference-between-a-left-join-and-a-left-outer-join/